# Change php location of composer

Tags: php, composer-php

How can I change the location of PHP used by composer?

I tried run the setup again, but it keep using the old one.

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
D:\servers\php_5_5_37_x86\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: D:\servers\php_5_5_37_x86\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:/Servers/php_5_4_39_x86/ext/php_curl.dll' - Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the path to your 'php folder' in 'PATH' variable on the system environment variables.

check this : 
https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Comment: It was that plus I had put the extension dir of php 5.5 pointing to php 5.4. Thanks.